# How can I activate c ++ 11 in my version of GCC (7.3.0) to install CMake?

Tags: c++11, gcc, cmake

I am trying to install cmake in my Dell Inspiron 15 500, but when a run the command

```
$ ./bootstrap
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.12.2, Copyright 2000-2018 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
C compiler on this system is: cc       
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find a C++ compiler that supports both C++11 and the specified C++ flags.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
The C++ flags are "".
They can be changed using the environment variable CXXFLAGS.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /home/jogabell/Descargas/cmake-3.12.2/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
```

How can I activate c ++ 11 in my version of GCC (7.3.0) to install CMake?

Comment: Just guessing, g++ is not installed on your computer. If you use Linux, try to execute "g++ --version" and see the output (do not include " in command).

Answer (score 0):

Use your package manager to install gcc-c++
example:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).